# Wix Bootstrapper Won't Run When Using ThemeFile

Tags: wix, themes, bootstrapper, burn

I have created a wix bootstrapper that runs fine on all computers when no theme file is used. If I use a theme file, it will run on my computer but not on anyone else's.

`<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >`
    `<bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="C:\eula.rtf"` 
        `ThemeFile="C:\myTheme.xml" />`
`</BootstrapperApplicationRef>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, look at the bundle log file on the other machines to see the error. Likely the message will indicate there is an issue loading the theme. If that is the case, make sure that all paths in the theme file to loose files (for example, the `Image` element `ImageFile` attribute) are relative paths. Finally, be sure to include the loose files as `Payload` elements in the `BootstrapperApplicationRef`.

Unlike a .wxs file, the theme file's loose files are not automatically included. That is why you must add the `Payload` elements yourself.