# Wix bootstrapper doesn't show license when using a custom theme

Tags: wix

I'm using `WixBootstrapperApplicationRef` with a custom theme to show a License up. I've added the theme as payload as I've seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143575/wix-bootstrapper-wont-run-when-using-themefile), but if I add the custom theme, the License Agreement is not shown.

The code I'm using is attached below:

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
  <Payload SourceFile="..\..\..\Libraries\InstallerFiles\graphics\UIDialog.bmp"/>
  <Payload SourceFile="..\..\..\Libraries\InstallerFiles\graphics\UIBanner.bmp"/>
  <Payload SourceFile="..\..\..\Libraries\InstallerFiles\graphics\UIBanner2.bmp"/>
  <Payload SourceFile="..\..\..\Libraries\InstallerFiles\graphics\CoreTheme.xml"/>
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="..\..\..\Libraries\InstallerFiles\licenses\License Agreement_Test.rtf" SuppressOptionsUI="yes" ThemeFile="..\..\..\Libraries\InstallerFiles\graphics\CoreTheme.xml" />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

And the ThemeFile looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Theme xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/thmutil/2010">
  <Window Width="500" Height="390" HexStyle="100a0000" FontId="0">[WixBundleName] Setup Wizard.</Window>
  <Font Id="0" Height="-12" Weight="500" Foreground="000000" Background="FFFFFF">Segoe UI</Font>
  <Font Id="1" Height="-18" Weight="575" Foreground="000000">Segoe UI</Font>
  <Font Id="2" Height="-16" Weight="500" Foreground="000000">Segoe UI</Font>
  <Page Name="Install">
    <Text X="175" Y="11" Width="-11" Height="64" FontId="1">Welcome to the [WixBundleName] Setup Wizard</Text>
    <Image X="0" Y="0" Width="164" Height="312" ImageFile="UIDialog.bmp" />
    <Static Height="1" Width="-0" X="0" Y="312" Visible="yes" />
    <Text Name="Welcome" X="175" Y="90" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="0">This Setup Wizard will install [WixBundleName] on your computer.</Text>
    <Text Name="Welcome" X="175" Y="141" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="0">It is recommended that you close all other applications before continuing.</Text>
    <Text Name="Welcome" X="175" Y="192" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="0">Click Install to continue, or Close to exit the Setup Wizard.</Text>
    <Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallCloseButton)</Button>
  </Page>
  <Page Name="Progress">
    <Image X="0" Y="0" Width="493" Height="58" ImageFile="UIBanner2.bmp" />
    <Static Height="1" Width="-0" X="0" Y="312" Visible="yes" />
    <Text X="11" Y="11" Width="-11" Height="64" FontId="1">[WixBundleName] Setup Wizard</Text>
    <Static Height="1" Width="-0" X="0" Y="58" />
    <Text X="11" Y="120" Width="-11" Height="25" FontId="2">#(loc.ProgressHeader)</Text>
    <Text X="11" Y="161" Width="70" Height="17" FontId="0">#(loc.ProgressLabel)</Text>
    <Text Name="OverallProgressPackageText" X="85" Y="161" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="0">#(loc.OverallProgressPackageText)</Text>
    <Progressbar Name="OverallCalculatedProgressbar" X="11" Y="183" Width="-11" Height="15" />
    <Button Name="ProgressCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.ProgressCancelButton)</Button>
  </Page>
  <Page Name="Modify">
    <Text X="175" Y="11" Width="-11" Height="64" FontId="1">Welcome to the [WixBundleName] Setup Wizard.</Text>
    <Image X="0" Y="0" Width="164" Height="312" ImageFile="UIDialog.bmp" />
    <Static Height="1" Width="-0" X="0" Y="312" Visible="yes" />
    <Text X="175" Y="90" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="0">The Setup Wizard allows you to remove the [WixBundleName] features from your computer.</Text>
    <Text X="175" Y="141" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="0">Click Uninstall to continue, or Close to exit the Setup Wizard.</Text>
    <Button Name="UninstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.ModifyUninstallButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="ModifyCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.ModifyCloseButton)</Button>
  </Page>
  <Page Name="Success">
    <Text X="175" Y="11" Width="-11" Height="64" FontId="1">Completed the [WixBundleName] Setup Wizard.</Text>
    <Image X="0" Y="0" Width="164" Height="312" ImageFile="UIDialog.bmp" />
    <Static Height="1" Width="-0" X="0" Y="312" Visible="yes" />
    <Text X="175" Y="90" Width="-11" Height="51" FontId="0">Click the Close button to exit the Setup Wizard</Text>
    <Button Name="SuccessCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.SuccessCloseButton)</Button>
  </Page>
  <Page Name="Failure">
    <Text X="175" Y="11" Width="-11" Height="64" FontId="1">The [WixBundleName] Setup Wizard was interrupted.</Text>
    <Image X="0" Y="0" Width="164" Height="312" ImageFile="UIDialog.bmp" />
    <Static Height="1" Width="-0" X="0" Y="312" Visible="yes" />
    <Text Name="FailureText" X="175" Y="90" Width="-11" Height="71" FontId="0">
      The [WixBundleName] Setup was interrupted. Your system has not been modified. To install this program at a later time, please run the installation again. Refer to the installation manual for further instructions.
    </Text>
    <Text Name="FailureMessageText" X="175" Y="161" Width="-11" Height="80" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes" />
    <Button Name="FailureCloseButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.FailureCloseButton)</Button>
  </Page>
</Theme>
```

What I would like to achieve is to show the License Agreement page right after the `Install` page. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reread that you wanted to add the license agreement after the install page but without modifying the boostrapper application, that isn't possible.

If you really want to modify the bootstrapper application to that extent, you will need to download the wix3 source from github and get to work understanding and modifying the WixStdBA.vcxproj into your own BA to define a new UI flow.

---

Your theme doesn't have a eula rich edit box definition so it won't show up.

Since you are using (I assume) the default WixStdBA.dll and are using one of the default themes you'll need to follow their structure to make use of the UI elements they have used. You can add some elements like checkboxes and I think text boxes but you're sort of limited as far as it goes with other interactive UI elements.

[Here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/BalExtension/wixstdba/Resources/RtfTheme.xml) is the link to the original RTFLicense theme.

Notice their Install page:

```
<Page Name="Install">
    <Richedit Name="EulaRichedit" X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="-70" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HexStyle="0x800000" />
    <Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" X="-11" Y="-41" Width="260" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox)</Checkbox>
    <Button Name="OptionsButton" X="-171" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallOptionsButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallCloseButton)</Button>
</Page>
```

If you want a EULA to show up on your first page, you must add a Richedit named `EulaRichedit` along with a checkbox named `EulaAcceptCheckbox`. Also, any of the interactive UI elements in the theme **must** keep the same name otherwise they will not work in your bootstrapper. In this case, if you don't have the checkbox, the Install button will be disabled forever.

This is a limitation of using the built-in bootstrapper without writing your own. You also can't add new buttons that do anything without modifying the bootstrapper application code your self. You are basically limited to moving UI elements around (if you really wanted to) and adding static text and checkboxes and maybe editable text boxes.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! :) It has really helped me out